# Как сделать курсив с наклоном влево?

Tags: android

Это возможно? Ничего не нахожу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@tse никогда не говори никогда :)

Если речь идет о `TextView/EditText` то можно. Надо использовать кастомный `Spannable`.

Например [втыкаем в Spanny](https://github.com/binaryfork/Spanny) и смотрим на  [CustomTypefaceSpan](https://github.com/binaryfork/Spanny/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/binaryfork/spannysample/CustomTypefaceSpan.java)

Чтобы сделать обратный наклон, надо всего лишь написать что-то типа:

```
paint.setTextSkewX(0.3f);
```

Остальное надеюсь дело техники...

Comment: Слышал бы ты стук моей упавшей челюсти :)

Comment: Вау! Спасибо, крутяяяяк!!